# EHCache CacheManager initialization error on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, ehcache

I'm using EHCache 2.6.0 programmatically (no ehcache.xml) in Google App Engine v1.7.0.

when I instantiate CacheManager using:

```
CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManager.create();
```

I got error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessDeclaredMembers)
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater$AtomicReferenceFieldUpdaterImpl.<init>(AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.java:217)
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicRefe...(length 9029)
```

I tried:

```
CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager();
```

and with monitoring off:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setMonitoring(Configuration.Monitoring.OFF.name());
configuration.setUpdateCheck(false);
CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager(configuration);
```

for both of them I got following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.ehcache.util.lang.VicariousThreadLocal
    at net.sf.ehcache.TransactionController.<init>(TransactionController.java:43)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:433)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:374)
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that Ehcache v2.6 is not compatible with the current AppEngine. I had to switch to a previous version of the ehcache to get it run. After a long try and error the version 2.4.7 seems to be stable. 'Obviously' the config provided by ehcache does not work. Here is how I had to configure it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" >
    <cacheManagerEventListenerFactory class="" properties=""/>
    <defaultCache
       maxElementsInMemory="10000"
       eternal="false"
       overflowToDisk="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="120"
       timeToLiveSeconds="120"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
    </defaultCache>
<!--Example sample cache-->
    <cache name="sid"
      maxElementsInMemory="100"
      eternal="false"
      timeToIdleSeconds="300"
      timeToLiveSeconds="300"
      memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
       />
</ehcache>
```

Answer (score 1):

AppEngine is a distributed system, where requests are automatically handled by multiple frontend instances. In such setup you can not use a cache implementation (EHCache) on frontend instances, because you will have multiple instances of EHCache running and writing to one EHCache will not reflect on other EHCaches.

Instead you should use AppEngine's own [memcache service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview).

Comment: but EHCache offer GAE support, see [link](http://ehcache.org/documentation/integrations/googleappengine)

Comment: OK, in this case it seems that EHCache wraps GAE cache. But you need to properly configure it: http://ehcache.org/documentation/integrations/googleappengine#configuring-ehcachexml

Comment: "Compatibility
Ehcache is compatible and works with Google App Engine. Google App Engine provides a constrained runtime which restricts networking, threading and file system access." . Network restrictions means it will not be distributed. Please correct me if I am wrong!!